# Show original query matches first and order then by another field

Tags: solr, search-engine, sunspot, sunspot-rails

In my DB I have documents with title and rating like the following (plus more fields)

- "UPS-node" "89"
- "UPS" "50"
- "kicik up" "95"

If a query like "UPS" is made I want the results returned in this order as shown above. First original term then stemmed terms and within ordered by the rating.

The index for the above uses `WordDelimiterFactory` and `PorterStemFilter`. Actually I am using two types for the title: title and title_stemmed in order to boost the original title over the stemmed one. However I cannot figure out how to sort by rating then. Right now the returned order is:

- "UPS" "50"
- "UPS-node" "89"
- "kicik up" "95"

I am using sunspot.
Does anyone have an idea how to achieve that?

EDIT: Boost
Right now I define my boosts like this:

```
def index
  if params[:query]
    search = Project.search do
      fulltext params[:query] do
        boost_fields :project_title => 3.0
        boost_fields :rating_total => 1.5
      end
    ..
```

EDIT: An idea is to separate the requests --> one for the original term and one for the stemmed term

```
search = Project.search do
    keywords params[:query] do
      fields(:project_title => 10.0, :repository_title => 10.0)
      fields(:author => 2.0, :part_values => 2.0)
      fields(:description)
    end
    order_by :rating_total, :desc
    paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => Kaminari.config.default_per_page
  end

  search_stemmed = Project.search do
    keywords params[:query] do
      fields(:project_title_stemmed)
    end
    order_by :rating_total, :desc
    paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => Kaminari.config.default_per_page
  end

  @projects = search.results.concat(search_stemmed.results).uniq!
```

But of course the pagination does not work then anymore? Any ideas how to fix this? I only want 10 results per page with first the original matches and then only the stemmed matches.

Comment: did you tried the boosting at the query time...?

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: can you try by increasing the boost value for rating than the title...?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean but I just tried project_title => 3.0 and rating_total => 6.0 and I get the same order of results